# django ORM join two model on a foreign key

Tags: python, django

*The title might be misleading, I'm not sure on how to express my problem*

I have two models declared this way:

```
class Record(models.Model):
    # autogen id as primary key
    name = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    value = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()


class Integration(models.Model):
    # autogen id as primary key
    action = models.FloatField()
    on_record = models.ForeignKey(Record, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

I have one `Record` per hour per day on an entire year, thus 24*365.
For each `Record`, there are **exactely ten (10)** `Integration`s, each having their distinct `action`.

What I need is a QuerySet on `Record` that has an "extra column" with the average of the related 10 Integration's `action`s. So

#### Record

| id | name | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 120.00 | 2020-01-01 00:00 |
| 2 | B | 85.00 | 2020-01-01 01:00 |

#### Integration

| id | action | on_record |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0x1 | 7.00 | 1 |
| 0x2 | 2.00 | 1 |
| 0x3 | 9.00 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 0x10 | 8.41 | 1 |
| 0x11 | 8.99 | **2 <-- next `Record`** |

### What I need

| id | name | value | date | integration_avg_action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 120.00 | 2020-01-01 00:00 | 8.17 |
| 2 | B | 85.00 | 2020-01-01 00:00 | 7.58 |

I was able to generate the average of the `Integration`s this way

```
Integration.objects
    .values('on_record')
    .annotate(avg=Avg('action'))
```

but this is as far as I've come to. I've tried [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and many `select_related()` but I'm more confused now than before. It looks to me as a simple `JOIN` but I can't find a way to get it via ORM.

Comment: can you still alter the models or is your proj live and no changes can be done?

Comment: @Neeraj no it's still on development, but it is agreed to be the most suiting representation of our problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want a QuerySet of `Record` you should annotate on that instead of on `Integration`. See the section [Following relationships backwards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards) in the documentation for aggregation.

```
Record.objects.annotate(integration_avg_action=Avg('integration__action'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If at all changing your models is not costly then you can add related name to your FK field:

```
class Record(models.Model):
    # autogen id as primary key
    name = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    value = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()


class Integration(models.Model):
    # autogen id as primary key
    action = models.FloatField()
    on_record = models.ForeignKey(Record, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='integration')
```

Then you can execute the following query:

```
Record.objects.all().annotate(integration_avg_action=Avg('integration__action')).values('name', 'value', 'date', 'integration_avg_action')
```